# How do I load Compiz preferences file through terminal?

Tags: unity, compiz

My Compiz GUI does not work (actually, it does work, but changes on it won't take any effect). I have a compiz preferences file (.profile) and I would like to load it through the terminal (since loading it directly throuhg compiz`s GUI will not work). How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: Reproduce compiz settings not taking effect? Actually, I wrote this over a year ago. I have changed my Ubuntu version in the meanwhile and now everything is working fine. Although I would still like to know how to load the settings through the terminal.